# filezilla server 530 User cannot log in

Tags: networking, permissions, ftp, filezilla

I am trying to setup filezilla server to access files remotely. I am able to connect and list the files using local address (192.168.x.x). Now I am trying to connect through dedicated IP over internet. I am getting the following error

```
Status: Connecting to 182.xxx.xxx.xxx:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 ZXDSL 831CII FTP version 1.0 ready at Wed May 28 16:21:48 2014
Command:    USER xyz
Response:   331 Enter PASS command
Command:    PASS ******
Response:   530 User xyz cannot log in.
Error:  Critical error
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

What I have done so for

- I have uninstalled IIS FTP services
- windows firewall is disabled
- SSL is disabled
- Filezilla server FTP server service is running
- Port forwading seems to working properly
- I am using windows 8.1

Filezilla server is listening at port 21 and in passive mode setting in Use Custom port range it is `11121` and in use the following IP I have entered `182.xxx.xxx.xxx`

What else could be the reason of the error

I have enabled the port forwarding for said modem using [this](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/ZTE/ZXDSL-831CII/Utorrent.htm) link

Comment: `Response: 220 ZXDSL 831CII FTP version 1.0` Surely it's not your FTP server, as FileZilla FTP sends another response. Make sure router/modem's (especially port forwarding) configuration is OK.

Comment: I have enabled the port forwarding using the following tutorial http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/ZTE/ZXDSL-831CII/Utorrent.htm for the said modem

Comment: Try another FTP server (for example, [this](http://www.pablosoftwaresolutions.com/html/quick__n_easy_ftp_server.html)). Do you get the same error?